Subfolder in asset volume only display folders and not files
I have a strange issue with one of the sub-folders in an asset volume where is only displaying the sub-folders and not the files in that folder. Oddly other sub folders are functioning and displaying fine in the same volume. I have the same problem if I'm accessing the folder from the assets section or adding an asset to an entry from that folder.
So for example:
photos/category-1 will show me both files and folders correctly.
photos/category-2 will only display the folders.
If I search for files in photos/category-2 however, the files are displayed correctly. I feel like I'm missing something obvious.
Version is Craft CMS 4.8.0
MySQL 8.0.37
PHP 8.0.30
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Sounds like a bug, better open an issue on GitHub.
